# Page source reveals part of my page isn't displaying

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a friend's project and I'm in charge of designing a simple website to interface with his databases. I have written the following code for one of his pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Narcissus-OTS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=./account.php" />-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("./common/database.php"); ?>
        <?php
            //Grabs user-submitted credentials from previous page
            $accountid = mysql_escape_string($_POST["acc"]);
            $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
            $confirmation = mysql_escape_string($_POST["passtwo"]);
            //Insures there is no duplicate database entry for accountid
            $querycheck = $db->query("
                SELECT *
                    FROM accounts a
                    WHERE a.name = $accountid
                ");
            $checkifone = $querycheck->rowCount();
            //If no duplicate entry...
            if ($checkifone == 1) {
                echo "There is already an account with that name; please choose a different account number.";
            } else {
            //Confirms if passwords match
                if ($password == $confirmation) {
                    $passhash = sha1($password);
                    $database = $db->query("
                        INSERT INTO accounts
                            VALUES (NULL , '$accountid', '$passhash', '65535', '0', '', '1', '0', '0', '1');
                    ");
                    echo "Your account has been successfully created.";
                //If passwords do not match
                } else {
                    echo "Your passwords did not match, please try again.";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page and view page source, it doesn't seem to show terminating `</body>` or terminating `</html>` tags. I've traced my code and can't see any missing semi-colons or parentheses. For the life of me I can't figure this one out. It displays the terminating tags properly only when the passwords do not match (the bottom-most nested else statement).

edit; and before anyone says it, I know `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated.

edit2; database.php looks like...

```
<?php
    $SERVER   = "localhost";
    $USERNAME = "redacted";
    $PASSWORD = "redacted";
    $DATABASE = "redacted";
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$DATABASE}; host={$SERVER}", $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Comment: what does database.php look like?

Comment: Make sure you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @RyanB, edited the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet to solve this problem and any other occurrences like this in the future is to `tail` your server log and determine what exactly the issue is.

For `apache2`:

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

For `nginx`:

`tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`